# ajax and check box

Tags: javascript, html, hide, show, show-hide

Pleas help me
I had a to radio

```
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" /> Male<br />
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" /> Female
<div class="content">
      <div id="male">male contetn</div>
      <div id="female">femalecontetn</div>
</div>
```

I want use ajax when i click radio value male
will show div id =male and hide id="female"
and 
 when i click radio value female
will show div id =female and hide id=male

Great Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See it in action.](http://jsbin.com/osese3/)

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" id="sex_male" /> Male<br />
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" id="sex_female" /> Female
<div class="content">
      <div id="male">male contetn</div>
      <div id="female">femalecontetn</div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function show(el) {
  el.style.display = "";
}
function hide(el) {
  el.style.display = "none";
}

document.getElementById("sex_male").onclick = function() {
  show(document.getElementById("male"));
  hide(document.getElementById("female"));
}

document.getElementById("sex_female").onclick = function() {
  show(document.getElementById("female"));
  hide(document.getElementById("male"));
}
```

Comment: @Thoman, please can you explain in what way it didn't work. I'm assuming that, without that information, @galambalazs will have difficulty knowing **what** to 'fix.'

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jquery here is the code for that:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#sex_male").click(function () {
            toggleVisibility(true);
        });
        $("#sex_female").click(function () {
            toggleVisibility(false);
        });
    });
    function toggleVisibility(isMale) {
        if (isMale) {
            $("#sex_female").hide();
            $("#sex_male").show();
        }
        else {
            $("#sex_male").hide();
            $("#sex_female").show();
        }
    }
```

Also the code example above my post should work.  You are probably loading it too early though.  If you put it at the bottom of your page it should work.